# Does Zebra Savanna require a specific RFID tag?

Tags: zebra-savanna

Does the Zebra Savanna require a specific RFID tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently any passive tag that is readable by the FX readers is passible through Savanna.  Please see your reader specs for the tags available.